# How do I implement restricted access to subsets in my database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I can restrict entire controller action access with `[Authorize(Roles=...)]` however, what about if I want to allow a user to for example look at the data of the other users in their own department (only).

Specifically what I mean is when I give a user the details of another user, the URL will be like this:
`myapp.com/user/details/45`

And they could quite easily just edit the `45` to be whatever they want. I want to restrict the access if the user the requested is not part of their own company (their company is currently in their session but that can be changed)

I can see a few different ways to do this, but I am just wondering what everyone's preference is based on experience. Here are some options:

1.Change the way access is done by editing the routing. `myapp.com/Company/4/User/4' where 4 is a psudoID which references an actual ID internally.
2.`myapp.com/OurCompany/User/4' < same but with a controller for ourcompany instead of generically companies.
3. Just check it internally by checking the requested user is in the same company: `myapp.com/User/42345'. My issue is that this has to be customized for each kind of request (users, products, related companies). But this is what I'm looking at right now.

EntityFramework actually has the power to reference the company members of the current user because when they log in I get their company entry and store it in the session. This allows easy access to the members of the company like so:
`SessionHandler.UserSession.CompanyTable.UserTable.Where(e=> e.UserID == id).FirstOrDefault();`

This seems odd to those who don't know about EF, but basically the subtable `UserTable` is a subset of all users referenced by the Foreign Key of the CompanyTable, which does indeed return the correct set of entities. The issue with this is that updating the entry in this way actually updates the entry in the SESSION but not inside the DATABASE, which is really bazaar to watch because it means the logged in users can seemingly make changes to the database but infact they are just being saved into the session. (staring at the database whist making these changes confirmed it, logging out and logging in nothing was saved, but `db.SaveChanges()` was correctly being called, just there were no changes to be made)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, for the love of everything good and holy, stop putting that in the session. The session shouldn't be used for this, regardless, and it's code smell of the worst kind.

What you're talking about is object-level permissions. The correct way to do that is to limit your queries with some identifying factor of the currently logged in user. Your entities need a concept of "ownership" for this work. In other words, they need a foreign key to some other entity that "owns" that particular instance. Since here you want to restrict by department, that means all your users need to be owned by departments. Then, for situations like this you can do something like:

```
db.Users.Where(m => m.DepartmentId == user.DepartmentId)
```

Where `user` here is the instance of the currently logged in user. By querying in this way, the subset of entities available to the user is restricted by the user, itself. Which means attempting to access a URL with id outside of that set will naturally result in a 404. A 404 is actually the best thing for this, because even though it's authorization based, returning a 403 lets you know something is there - you just can't access it. For a hacker, this kind of information is half the battle. A 404 being returned gives you zero information. It might not exist or it might just not be available to *you*.